# Export file from android app

Tags: java, android, permissions, export, opencsv

I would export my data into download folder of internal sd. Then, i have add the permission in manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I must add also the permission to write to internal storage?

Then i call a method that include this:

```
String file = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

So, where i export my file? In what folder? Can i change this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude just print your file String , it will tell you the path, If you have added SDCARD in your Phone/Emulator it will give u "/sdcard/.." , where as if no sdcard in that case file will have null object.